# Copy using the folder names from .csv

Tags: powershell

I have a .csv in this format (with two columns ID and DisplayName) under D:\temp
ID            DisplayName
jdoe         Doe, John
msmith       Smith, Mark
lpratt       Pratt, Liz
....... and so on

There is a folder (E:\data)on the server under which there are folders with userid with some data already. For ex:
E:\data\jdoe, E:\data\msmith and so on. I want to write a script that will create a new folder E:\New_data\Smith, Mark and copy the data from E:\data\msmith.

I tried this code:

```
   $csv = Import-Csv D:\Temp\temp.csv
   ForEach ($obj in $csv.ID) {
   Foreach ($obj1 in $csv.DisplayName) {
   copy-item D:\Data\$obj D:\New_data\$obj1 -Recurse -Force
   }
   }
```

But this one is copying all the folders in the old location to every folder being copied to the new location. I kindly request you to let me know what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add, I am trying to implement this in Powershell. PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  2273

Comment: Well this kinda looks like youre variables are not getting filled as expected, did you do some basic debugging and made sure that `D:\Data\$obj` is actually an valid path? Just print out the Paths in the foreach to check.

Comment: Yes I did try $csv.ID and $csv.DisplayName echoes the variables on the screen. I just don’t know how to parse the .csv line by line and then extract the source and destination folder names and use it in the copy command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Import-Csv`, each row is loaded as a `pscustomobject` with fields that match the column headers.  In your case, you want to iterate through each of these (your double `foreach` doesn't actually accomplish anything):

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path D:\Temp\temp.csv
foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    $source = $row.ID
    $dest = $row.DisplayName
    Copy-Item -Path "D:\Data\$source" -Destination "D:\New_data\$dest" -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was scratching my head all day yesterday to figure this out. I can't thank you enough. God Bless you!!!!